# How to get item from HTML select in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

**Note:**

I know there's a bunch of question like mine but I really try them but any works.

I'm trying to get the selected option by the user in my endpoint but it doesn't working.

**I've tried:**

To write the attribute name on the select html tag.
In the backend I tried this two options
`type_user = request.form.get('type_user')` and this
`type_user = request.form['type_user']`

I use debbuger mode and see that auth.py is not receiving any data just a  `None`.

**register.html**

```
#I don't know if it is for the desabled attribute, if the user 
#is not logged so he cannot create a admin account only a normal account.
{% if g.user['type'] == 0 %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type_user">Type of User <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
          <select class="form-control" id="type_user" name="type_user" required>
            <option value="0">Admin</option>
            <option value="1">User</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type_user">Type of User <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
          <select class="form-control" id="type_user" name="type_user" required disabled>
            <option value="1">User</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
```

**auth.py**

```
@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        type_user = int(request.form.get('type_user'))
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        print(type_user)
        print(first_name)
        if not (first_name and last_name and type_user and username and password):
            error = "Please fill all requiered fields"

        elif db.execute(
            'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'User {} is already registered.'.format(username)

        if error is None:
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, type, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                (first_name, last_name, type_user, username, generate_password_hash(password))
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/register.html')
```

**Error:**

> File "D:\Dev\patterns-project\study_room\auth.py", line 15, in
>   register
>         -----> type_user = request.form['type_user'] <-----    File "d:\dev\patterns-project\my-venv\lib\site- 
>         packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 442, in **getitem**
>          raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)

Comment: I drop the disable Attribute and works. If there any solution with disable attribute please tell me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of having a dropdown list that's disabled if you then want to get the user input on the back end?

Comment: Yep it's a dropdown _<selected>_ tag, but I need if there's no admin session just register a normal user. Thanks for u help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm simplifying my answer to be more clear.

**register.html** - no need to change that.  What you've got works.

**auth.py** - minor change required.  The the if/else statement added below to your code:

```py
@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']

        ### Start of changed section ###
        # The line below will be None if type_user is disabled
        # type_user = int(request.form.get('type_user'))
        if "type_user" in request.form:
            # Current user must be an admin and have the option to select
            # the type_user for the new user, so read it here.
            type_user = request.form["type_user"]
        else:
            # The type_user field in the form must be disabled.
            # This means a  standard user or anonymouse person
            # must be registering a new user.  So the new user
            # must be a standard user.
            type_user = 1
        ### End of changed section ###

        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        print(type_user)
        print(first_name)
        if not (first_name and last_name and type_user and username and password):
            error = "Please fill all requiered fields"

        elif db.execute(
            'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'User {} is already registered.'.format(username)

        if error is None:
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, type, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                (first_name, last_name, type_user, username, generate_password_hash(password))
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/register.html')
```

The problem with using `disabled` in the HTML is that it makes the `<select>` totally unavailable.  Checking for `type_user` in the dictionary handles this case as shown above and below:

```py
if "type_user" in request.form:
    type_user = request.form["type_user"])
else:
    type_user = 1
```

Thanks @roganjosh for pointing out my original mistake focusing on the `<div>`.

Implementation here: https://github.com/johnhut/flask/tree/so-q56338730

Comment: It's not the `<div>`, you've also removed `disabled`, which is the actual issue

Comment: Ok my bad.  You're right, the `<div>` doesn't make a difference.  By definition `disabled` means the `<select>` is not available.  So I think `None` is the correct value to get returned for a disabled select.